# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. (W030)

Tags: javascript, jshint

I know there are a lot of similar questions, and I read some of them. I even re-read the [MDN of the ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) again, but I still don't understand why JSHint shows me the aforementioned error for the following code:

```
passHasNumber ? strength++ :
        passHasTwoNumbers ? strength++ :
        passHasCapitalLetter ? strength++ :
        passHasTwoCapitalLetters ? strength++ :
        passHasWhitespace ? strength++ :
        passHasSymbols ? strength++ :
        passVeryBad.innerHTML = `Only lowercase letters, huh?
        You can do better than that!`; // error appears here
```

I prefer not having code with errors, so I would appreciate a different take on this code that is as clean, if possible; I don't like to comment the code with the `/* jshint -W030 */` comment.

P.S.: I get the same error on the first line of my file, which is the `use strict` statement, but with back ticks. How to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're abusing the conditional operator as an `if` statement - JSHint is seeing the orphaned expression and complaining about it. Use `if` / `else` instead:

```
if (passHasNumber || passHasTwoNumbers || passHasCapitalLetter || passHasTwoCapitalLetters || passHasWhitespace || passHasSymbols) {
  strength++;
} else {
  passVeryBad.innerHTML = `Only lowercase letters, huh?
  You can do better than that!`; // error appears here
}
```

You should only use the conditional operator when you need to use the *expression it evaluates to* in something, for example:

```
const foo = condition ? 'foo' : 'error!';
```

But, it sounds like you *might* want to increment `strength` for every truthy boolean, which makes a bit more sense than incrementing `strength` only *once*, in which case:

```
const strength = passHasNumber + passHasTwoNumbers + passHasCapitalLetter + passHasTwoCapitalLetters + passHasWhitespace + passHasSymbols;
if (strength === 0) {
  passVeryBad.innerHTML = `Only lowercase letters, huh?
  You can do better than that!`; // error appears here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I learned that `strength`, which was declared as `let strength = 0` can accept Boolean operators and add them together. Also, for posterity, I found a way to cirvumvent the `use strict` problem: add `"strict": "global"` in your JSHint config.